# R How to use "sort" function at "period.apply"?

Tags: r, function, statistics, apply, xts

I want to order my time series in descending order (from maximum value to minimum value) for each year.

1. At the first time, I apply the function "sort" with "apply", here it works but all dates are mixed.

   ```
   library(xts) 
   library(PerformanceAnalytics)

   data(edhec) 
   head(edhec)

   edhec_4yr <- edhec["1997/2001"] 
   ep <- endpoints(edhec_4yr, "year")

   # "sort" function with apply Ok 
   s.ap=apply(edhec_4yr[,1],2,sort,decreasing = TRUE)
   s.ap
   ```

To separate the descending order of the values for each year, I try to apply the "sort" function with "period.apply" but it only gives the first value (maximum value) for each year!

My goal is to have all the data but just in descending order for each year.

```
>  #"sort" with period.apply (Juste the first value for each year!
> Why!!!!)
>     
>     s.per.ap=period.apply(edhec_4yr[,1], INDEX = ep, function(x) apply(x,2,sort,decreasing = TRUE))
>     s.per.ap
```

Indeed, I want to have this:

```
    Convertible Arbitrage
1997-06 0.0212
1997-07 0.0193
1997-05 0.0156
1997-08 0.0134
1997-02 0.0123
1997-09 0.0122
1997-01 0.0119
1997-10 0.0100
1997-04 0.0086
1997-03 0.0078
1997-12 0.0068
1997-11 0.0000

1998-11 0.0269
1998-02 0.0146
1998-01 0.0145
1998-03 0.0144
1998-04 0.0126
1998-12 0.0113
1998-07 0.0060
1998-05 0.0056
1998-06 -0.0006
1998-09 -0.0196
1998-10 -0.0214
1998-08 -0.0319
......
```

Can you helpe me how to improve my function with "period.apply" !

Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you explain why you want to do this. Otherwise this is likely an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 3):

Using `sort` with `period.apply()` does not return just the first value. It returns an xts with a row for each year and a column for each month, with the columns sorted in descending order.

```
R> period.apply(edhec_4yr[,1], ep, function(x) apply(x,2,sort,decreasing = TRUE))
             [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
1997-12-31 0.0212 0.0193 0.0156 0.0134 0.0123 0.0122
1998-12-31 0.0269 0.0146 0.0145 0.0144 0.0126 0.0113
1999-12-31 0.0243 0.0219 0.0166 0.0140 0.0136 0.0124
2000-12-31 0.0267 0.0243 0.0227 0.0223 0.0179 0.0162
2001-12-31 0.0344 0.0182 0.0162 0.0157 0.0142 0.0117
             [,7]   [,8]    [,9]   [,10]   [,11]   [,12]
1997-12-31 0.0119 0.0100  0.0086  0.0078  0.0068  0.0000
1998-12-31 0.0060 0.0056 -0.0006 -0.0196 -0.0214 -0.0319
1999-12-31 0.0102 0.0101  0.0096  0.0082  0.0048  0.0045
2000-12-31 0.0149 0.0141  0.0093  0.0052 -0.0002 -0.0081
2001-12-31 0.0091 0.0080  0.0078  0.0033  0.0012 -0.0094
```

The example output of what you want simply cannot be an xts/zoo object, because xts/zoo objects must have an ordered index.

Comment: Thank you Joshua Ulrich for your response. My goal is to extract the ten (10) lower values of the parametres for each year. I thought to make the descending order values of  parameters for each year and then extract the last ten values with the function "tail". But with the "sort" function with "period.apply" does not work for long time series (40 years). Have any ideas how to solve this problem with other way. thanks again